# Set Content View didnt work on my HomeFragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have `setContentView(R.Id.fragment_home)` but it didn't work on my Fragment class and it says `Cannot resolved method setContentView 'setContentView(int)'` does anyone know about this. Here`s my Code:

```
package com.thesis.artificialintelligence;

import android.app.Activity;          
import android.os.Bundle;         
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;        
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;       
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;   
import android.view.LayoutInflater;   
import android.view.View;   
import android.view.ViewGroup;   
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {    
    super.onAttach(activity);    
}

@Override    
public void onDetach() {    
    super.onDetach();    
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't call setContentView() method inside your fragment you only inflate your custom design by calling inflater.inflate() method in onCreateView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `setContentView` in Fragments.

You load it in `onCreateView` using the inflater like you already are and return it.

If you need a reference to any of your view elements you also look them up in `onCreateView` by doing `rootView.findViewById(...)` in your case.

Your code might work if you remove `setContentView`